# Isabelle: generic datatypes and equivalence

Tags: generics, types, isabelle, unification

I'm just starting making my type generic in Isabelle now i get funny error messages once i start using parenthesis.

```
theory Scratch
imports Main
begin
no_notation plus (infixl "+" 65)

datatype typeA = aa
datatype typeB = bb
datatype ('a, 'b) genericType = cc | 
                                plus 'a 'b (infixr "+" 35)

lemma test1 : "x + y ≡ x + y"
by auto
lemma test2 : "x + y + z ≡ x + y + z"
by auto
lemma test3 : "x + (y + z) ≡ x + y + z"
by auto
lemma test4 : "(x + y) + z ≡ x + y + z"
lemma test5 : "(aa + aa) + aa ≡ aa + aa + aa"
lemma test6 : "(cc + cc) + cc ≡ cc + cc + cc"
lemma test7 : "(cc + aa) + cc ≡ cc + aa + cc"
lemma test8 : "(aa + cc) + cc ≡ cc + aa + cc"
```

Everything is fine with test1-3, but test 4 and 5 result in this error:

```
Type unification failed: Occurs check!

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  op ≡ ((x + y) + z) :: ((??'a, ??'b) genericType, ??'c) genericType ⇒ prop
Operand:   x + y + z :: (??'a, (??'b, ??'c) genericType) genericType
```

and respectivly:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "typeA" and "(_, _) genericType"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  op ≡ ((aa + aa) + aa) :: ((typeA, typeA) genericType, typeA) genericType ⇒ prop
Operand:   aa + aa + aa :: (typeA, (typeA, typeA) genericType) genericType
```

test6 and weirdly test7/8 are fine again. Any more replacement of "cc" with "aa" leads to the same problem though.

PS: can i somehow specifiy the types 'a and 'b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two types in Isabelle are only equal when they really are syntactically equal. An equation where the left-hand side and the right-hand side have different types is not well-typed and will lead to an error message.

You defined `+` to be right-associative, so `x + y + z` is just an abbreviation for `x + (y + z)`. The lemmas `test1` to `test3` are therefore trivially true, since the two sides of the equation are syntactically equal terms.

In `test4` and `test5`, the left-hand sides have type `((_,_) genericType, _) genericType`. The right-hand sides, on the other hand, have type `(_, (_,_) genericType) genericType`.

To illustrate it a bit better, I will write `+` for `genericType` in infix: the left-hand sides have type `(_ + _) + _`; the right-hand sides have `_ + (_ + _)`. These two types are *not* syntactically equal and therefore different types. They are obviously isomorphic, but still different.

The fact that `test6` to `test8` are type-correct has to do with polymorphism: `cc` is polymorphic with schematic type variables `'a` and `'b` that can be instantiated to anything, and, importantly, if `cc` occurs in a term several times, the type variables can be instantiated to different types in every occurrence. This is *not* possible with variables like `x`, `y`, and `z` from the earlier examples.

Note, however, that while `test6` to `test8` can be type-checked, they are quite obviously false, as QuickCheck will tell you.

As for `specifying` the type variables: You can annotate terms with types, e.g. `x + y :: (typeA, typeB) genericType` or `(x :: typeA) + (y :: typeB)`.

Comment: I understand, that they are not equal. My problem is not, that the lemmas are in part obviously not true. My problem is, that i can't even state the term.

Comment: I understand, that they are not equal. My problem is not, that the lemmas are in part obviously not true. My problem is, that i can't even state the term.  As for the specification i mean it more like tospecify 'a and 'b. Sorry, missused enter a couple of times

Comment: Okay, i understand it now. Thanks for the answer. Guess == is not what i'm looking for :/     I want to define equality for term like above (the usefull ones) with axiomization. Can you point me somewhere?